# What type of Autoencoder for text similarity?

Tags: neural-network, nlp, autoencoder

I don't have any experience working on neural networks before,so any help would be highly appreciated. I am solving the following task: I want to find the similarity score between sentence pairs. My idea to solve this is to generate the embeddings for each word in the sentence and feed the vectors to an encoder which will learn to aggregate these many inputs to one lower representation sequence vector. And use cosine similarity between this sequence vectors to find the similarity score. 
My question is do you have any suggestions on which type of autoencoder or neural network architecture would work better for my case.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to train an AutoEncoder to learn the similarities between two embeddings of sentences. First, to encode the sentence, we can use [Google's Universal Sentence Encoder](https://towardsdatascience.com/use-cases-of-googles-universal-sentence-encoder-in-production-dd5aaab4fc15). This will generate vectors for us.

Since we have our vectors from a highly trained model, we can now directly calculate the similarity score using cosine similarity.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But on my task, I have to do a comparison of different approaches for sentence embedding. I have already applied USE and now I would like to see how autoencoders perform for this task.